# TypeScript - Add dynamically named property to return type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Let's say I have a function that takes an object, a key and a value, then returns a new object that extends the original object adding the key and value.

```
function addKeyValue(obj: Object, key: string, value: any) {
  return {
    ...obj,
    [key]: value
  }
}
```

**QUESTION:**
How can I type this function so that if I call it like so:

```
const user = addKeyValue({ name: 'Joe' }, 'age', 30);
```

The compiler knows that {user} is of type `{ name: string, age: number }`

**NOTE:**
I know I can do this without a function, but the goal of this question is to do it with a function. (This example is based on a more complicated problem and has been simplified for brevity).

Here's what I was thinking, but it doesn't work. :(

```
function addKeyValue<TInput>(
    obj: TInput,
    key: string,
    value: any): TInput & { [key]: typeof value } {

    return {
        ...obj,
        [key]: value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the caller's point of view, you probably want the signature to be something like one of these:

```
declare function addKeyValue<T extends {}, K extends keyof any, V>(obj: T, key: K, value: V): 
  T & Record<K, V>;
const user = addKeyValue({ name: 'Joe' }, 'age', 30); //  { name: string; } & Record<"age", number>
user.age // number
user.name // string
```

That's the pre-TypeScript 2.8 version, in which intersection is the best way to represent what you're doing.  You might not be happy with the type `{name: string} & Record<"age", number>`} but it acts like what you want.

You could also use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types):

```
declare function addKeyValue2<T extends {}, K extends keyof any, V>(obj: T, key: K, value: V):
  { [P in keyof (T & Record<K, any>)]: P extends K ? V : P extends keyof T ? T[P] : never };
const user2 = addKeyValue2({ name: 'Joe' }, 'age', 30); //  { age: number; name: string; } 
user2.age // number
user2.name // string
```

This has the advantage of the return type looking like what you expect, but the disadvantage of being complex and possibly brittle (might not always behave as expected with unions, etc).

Another possible advantage of this version is that if `key` overlaps the keys of `obj`, the property type will be overwritten:

```
const other2 = addKeyValue2({ name: 'Joe', age: 30 }, 'name', false); 
//  { name: boolean; age: number }
```

instead of intersected, which is probably not what you want:

```
const whoops = addKeyValue({ name: 'Joe', age: 30 }, 'name', false).name; // never
// boolean & string ==> never
```

---

None of that makes the implementation type check properly.  For that you should use whatever [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) will do the job:

```
  return {
    ...(obj as any), // simplest way to silence the compiler
    [key]: value
  }
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: jcalz comes to my rescue again, many thanks.

I think I prefer how the conditional type method maps the return type - I agree that although the code is more complicated, the outputted return type is more readable than the intersection type.

However (something I forgot to state) I need to preserve optionality of existing properties, which the 2nd method surprisingly doesn't do. I don't understand why it doesn't preserve it though given something like this trivial example does? 

`declare function clone<T>(input: T): { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }`

Comment: It's the `[P in keyof T | K]:` that makes the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) not [homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) and thus the modifiers on the properties of `T` are lost.  There's probably some way to preserve them but it gets even more annoying to implement.

Comment: Okay it's not pretty but I was able to tweak your 1st example to give a nice merged return type like your 2nd example does but retaining optionality. `declare function addKeyValue<T extends {}, K extends keyof any, V>(obj: T, key: K, value: V): { [P in keyof (T & Record<K, V>)]: (T & Record<K, V>)[P] }`

Comment: yeah I edited the 2nd example to something vaguely similar.