# Accepting different function return types for dynamic property names in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function

### Foreword

First and foremost, I want to mention that I have already referenced seemingly related questions here on Stack Overflow, such as this one [Stack Overflow #52204566](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204566/typescript-add-dynamically-named-property-to-return-type), but none of them appear to actually resolve the issue I am currently experiencing, so I am opening this new question.

### My Code

Here is my [TSX source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCgeirgBUBPMJAZwuADsYkpN0k4ABR4sIHRszgBvOBxQgkALjgsYUTgHMANLPlIAMhADuPZavUdtK5mmCszazQG0AujszAANiBYOLG1x0AC1wkI2hPABM-TR1VFCgWIOAwXxVHS0C4MCIAN2AIAFc08004AB9ZQs9PHQ4kAA8YGMsKqpq4AF8AbnYuHj40AQBlGzsWCQEZQqhPFqs5BXmu3vJObl5+OAAxLxBJ6TgZufT-HUjgIgxoeZ0iT1QWJAB9SJRuW7gYYBgH5Z6+htBiMYAkkikDtNZp9FkpTrE4CAIJEkCdSpYdGgIKpnpxnmgiBcYCUMhoVoCBltBJ4UPUYJCjtD4RjdEtmWSAZQ1v1NkMhCIxIIcKlpBQ4NkBRxlMJEmJJloxXAUDVRkhbPY4Kr1RMmEhAorlZ5dt40sb9rr9eRxYbhqDEslUspbWCHZNLdaatTaUhidKaXS3S4KJ0KBRMIUOBgChw4B5PBsAEIMfTAVQACieDwwy0q6ICbiVNWUUmOnycAGskAx5i5lLSGJ0siB3mgggBpKufFEsS5ISId6vsgCU81cq3Dke+YljXkTydTMAzqLVzXZbTzWUNxdL7J0Fc77NrSo4DabLfbB7z51Yvf7l9JrhHhyc3dvA5r-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-f9eh8VIAAGzCyhwAC0HMACRSGg9MAwonTM50AnjflahiBoAlSO9qKdMouVUOYUti1N4qVd12MwLjV0aATRNwAAjONontbl1R0ygv2C0gTOs5KXO8-z1sM0LXNaSwErs07fMC3onQe9wPjPM82si2r3XhbLC5sSgHEqcHvHo3AuXA3AJVM1potSNnSvAwJQ47VH4pK9UkdR4rLBgLSVs24zLNs6InM837ru24HHOe97ze+y79fu13wcsKHPaWA8Ecx6oTjEy4nRK9XtIV7tVNUDTatjVyjSQLA0V8NUWA-lOMYys3aYyE3Yg6DaYysNfNRmiw9+eM69opE-8lenSXsK-y7NChAVIoViLnXgE8BIrY6A8B8LJGC+B9CFErPgHQ+BhjlgYEYZUlYoD4DcKbQ4sI4i3xKMQgAqggfQH84w+HBnschlC4h2nBI6dILoUj0I-iEBQ4RZjRDgFwsIERIj0K6HARQ+CZCwk+NXNU4xQbuD2CSfwWR4hvxYRuAsAieFRH+LAy+HAFTqxEtQpRzgGoznjDwJMz00zUI4c-R+KDjjIIIN8X4SB8BDkMd1GR2pQawP-FY+cQEyEUI-jfWRd8CDOJQbCTx3jqqqOYWkSRgMMJIhRJ9fwXRXABNnEEmxSSHT2Pkq-ZJTjZguKcPgOJKCMmolwV4-BWihH+LkoEqA1iFxphabw+hz8v4+g-vgGJBB6meE8V1B48BkgaCCMDOZ3BIi21gbCLqzklwQKCFAqAPhdb4yCMA0SoCIqXQaMMVAUBWyrLCIgJAGhEYNA4uAq52zoEsDjhxDY6khLMzTLzb5o1masTShATgaZ8DlHiQQDQwBJmOVmfM4Aiy+wrLkoihZQQlm23GvFJAYAaRDBcjUNMRAzkXK2Sg3KzYoDlgEtzMmSsaV0s8biogBL+DEs8GmKgaZcoAB0qDMsLtShIdKqBWHwNzI2oraV1xYHxAARCwQoKUngAEdChXRgIqgSrKjF4o5USklvKBVCrFQJflLAhyyvFZK6Vtr5VKpVWqpAmrtXWH4Lq+FxFi7nQgA8XGEANDnyKe-UaXUZoUSpjTeVtslX6N1eLWN-c3Z20VformsJFWYVpJdHAxRPAMAuTAAAkhwa6AAJOgABZfQTMpChyxSAE4GLkVYtRQHTocAqDLxElIS6113gGHuo9GxqDiEuPwL48YLiZ2sCLuNAdV0eDDruh9Ps47K2hG0ZEKdvSoguIPXZYuoll1DtuqOh4T1un4BcmAZgYJNIcCnSYlxJjF1GPPauy9G6b3pnwIILwEAllTrDakOdTCHRsCMeKT5nFUkKB0OM0RxZWRwmguM-45V0OGWMsiVErVcPKGZoq3msJOg5t5uM4WIVtqr3XoqY65BOhAA) on the TypeScriptLang.org Playground, where you can see the error on the Errors tab on the right side of the page.

I am also attaching my TSX code here (below) for reference, but you will not be able to see the TS errors here on Stack Overflow.

```js
import React from 'react'

// Types
interface PersonType { name: string, nameLower: string, species: string[], films: string[], homeworld: string, starships: string[], previous: string | null, next: string | null };
interface SpeciesType { url: string, name: string };
interface FilmType { url: string, director: string, release_date: string, title: string };
interface StarshipType { url: string, name: string, model: string, cost_in_credits: string };
interface PlanetType { url: string, name: string };

interface PersonProps {
  person: PersonType,
  allSpecies: SpeciesType[],
  allFilms: FilmType[],
  allStarships: StarshipType[],
  allPlanets: PlanetType[]
}

function filterByList(select: string | string[], all: {url: string, [key: string]: any}[], matchKey: string, desiredKey: string): string[];
function filterByList(select: string | string[], all: {url: string, [key: string]: any}[], matchKey: string, desiredKey: string[]): { [desiredKey: string]: string }[];
function filterByList(select: string | string[], all: {url: string, [key: string]: any}[], matchKey: string, desiredKey: string | string[]) {
  return (
    [select].flat().map((mK: string) => {
      const matched = all.find(item => item[matchKey] === mK);
      if (matched) {
        if (Array.isArray(desiredKey)) {
          return desiredKey.reduce((obj: Record<string, any>, key: string) => {
            obj[key] = matched[key] ?? null;
            return obj;
          }, {});
        }
        return matched[desiredKey] ?? null;
      }
    }) ?? []
  )
};

const generateLabeledList = (label: string, className: string, list: string[]): false | JSX.Element => (
  list.length > 0 &&
    <div className={`person--${className}`}>
      <strong>{label}: </strong>
      {
        list.length > 1
          ? <ul className={`person--${className}--items person--${className}--items__list`}>
              {list.map((item: string) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
            </ul>
          : <span className={`person--${className}--items person--${className}--items__single`}>{list[0]}</span>
      }
    </div>
);

export default function Person({ person, allSpecies, allFilms, allStarships, allPlanets }: PersonProps) {
  const searchTerms = ['Luke', 'Skywalker'],
        { name, species: speciesURLs, films: filmURLs, starships: starshipURLs, homeworld: homeworldURL } :
        { name: string, species: string[], films: string[], starships: string[], homeworld: string } = person,
        films: string[] = filterByList(filmURLs, allFilms, 'url', 'title'),
        species: string[] = filterByList(speciesURLs, allSpecies, 'url', 'name'),
        starships: { name: string, model: string }[] = filterByList(starshipURLs, allStarships, 'url', ['name', 'model']),
        homeworld: string[] = filterByList(homeworldURL, allPlanets, 'url', 'model');
  let highlightedName = name;
  if (searchTerms.length) {
    const regexSearch = new RegExp(searchTerms.map(term => `(${term})`).join('|'), 'gi');
    highlightedName = highlightedName
      .replaceAll(regexSearch, '<mark>$&</mark>')
      .replaceAll(/(<\/mark>)<mark>/g, '$1<mark class="subsequent">')
      .replaceAll(/(<\/mark>\s)<mark>/g, '$1<mark class="subsequent space">');
  }
  console.log({starships});
  return (
    <div className="person">
      <div className="person--name" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: highlightedName}} />
      {generateLabeledList('Species', 'species', species)}
      {generateLabeledList('Homeworld', 'homeworld', homeworld)}
      {generateLabeledList('Appears in', 'films', films)}
      {generateLabeledList('Piloted', 'starships', starships
        .map(({ name, model } : { name: string, model: string }) => name === model ? name : `"${name}" ${model}`))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### The Issue & My Approach

I am building a function in TypeScript which—for parameter—accepts any arbitrary property name, or array of property names. If a single property name (string) is provided, the function returns an array of the values of that property for the objects being evaluated.

If an array of property names is provided, the function returns an array of keyed objects, where each object in the array contains the strings passed to the function as an array as its keys and the values pertaining to each for the objects being evaluated.

I am using [function overloading](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-function-overloading/) to handle my different return types which resolved many of the errors I was experiencing initially. This final error appears to relate to the return type when I pass an array of property names (which will be used as the keys in the objects returned as an array from the function).

### The Error

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Type '{ [desiredKey: string]: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; model: string; }[]'.

Type '{ [desiredKey: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; model: string; }': name, model
```

The main lines to pay mind to, regarding the error, are:

- **Line 17:** Creating the function overload for this return type, where `desiredKey` is an array of strings `string[]` and the return type is currently set to `{ [desiredKey: string]: string }[]` (tried making use of computed property names)

```
function filterByList(select: string | string[], all: {url: string, [key: string]: any}[], matchKey: string, desiredKey: string[]): { [desiredKey: string]: string }[];
```

- **Line 55:** Invoking that function with the argument for parameter `desiredKey` as an array of strings `string[]`, per the overload format I created for this case

```
starships: { name: string, model: string }[] = filterByList(starshipURLs, allStarships, 'url', ['name', 'model']),
```

- **Lines 72-74:** Iterating/mapping over the returned array of objects, destructuring the `name` and `model` properties from each object as I iterate over the array

```
{generateLabeledList('Piloted', 'starships', starships
  .map(({ name, model } : { name: string, model: string }) => name === model ? name : `"${name}" ${model}`))
}
```

I've been troubleshooting this for several hours now with no "good" solution working as it should for this, without having to break the function into several sub-functions, and even then, this issue of dynamic keys usually results in an error. As this function should be able to be used for any object, **I cannot explicitly list the keys as optional properties**.

I am looking for a way, preferably using my current approach or one similar, to resolve this error so the function can take in an array of strings and return an array of objects with those strings as its keys as expected.

Any ideas here as to how to get this working would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

A few resources I've been referencing while working through this:

- **Conditional Types** (artsy.github.io): https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/
- **Conditional Types** (typescriptlang.org): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html
- **Function Overloading** (dmitripavlutin.com): https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-function-overloading/

Comment: 1. Your playground is deeply broken, it shows ~20 errors. Better isolate the issue before demoing it

Comment: 2. The easiest way to achieve what you want is just to cast the type - `... = filterByList(...) as { name: string, model: string }[]`

Comment: 3. What you actually want, is to make your typings match the runtime logic of your function (filterByList) which is probably not impossible, but there's no reason to do it as it boils down to necessity to repeat the function's algorythm at the level of typings system. This is gonna be super complex, and this is gonna be fragile once you need to change the logic of the function. I'd recommend to follow the KISS principle (keep it simple), and go with solution #2

Comment: @KostiantynKo Looks like the playground is requiring me to import `React` where it didn't before. Just add `import React from 'react'` to the top, and it should leave only the one relevant error.

Comment: @KostiantynKo wanted to check back in and see if you had any feedback now that I have fixed the TS playground

Comment: This is too much to parse through. I managed to reproduce the problem with fewer lines of code and getting rid of irrelevant implementation detail. I tried to suggest an edit but you're edit queue is full. Here's a [link](shorturl.at/bhDV1) to the TS playground.

I have a feeling you can use generics and type constraints here.

Comment: By the way, one thing that I noticed is that you annotate types that can be inferred by TS. That's not required and best practice is to let TS infer what it can. So `const x = 24;` is generally preferred over `const x: number = 24;`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, took me a while to parse through the code, but basically `{ [desiredKey: string]: string; }` cannot be assigned to `{ name: string; model: string; }` because the second type is narrower. You can use generics in your function signature to define the return type based on the `desiredKey` values.

Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCgeirgBUBPMJAZwuADsYkpN0k4ABR4sIHRszgBvOBxQgkALjgsYUTgHMANLPlIAMhADuPZavUdtK5mmCszazQG0AujszAANiBYOLG1x0AC1wkI2hPABM-TR1VFCgWIOAwXxVHS0C4MCIAN2AIAFc08004AB9ZQs9PHQ4kAA8YGMsKqpq4AF8AbnYuHj40AQBlGzsWCQEZQqhPFqs5BXmu3vJObl5+OAAxLxBJ6TgZufT-HUjgIgxoeZ0iT1QWJAB9SJRuW7gYYBgH5Z6+htBiMYAkkikDtNZp9FkpTrE4CAIJEkCdSpYdGgIKpnpxnmgiBcYCUMhoVoCBltBJ4UPUYJCjtD4RjdEtmWSAZQ1v1NkMhCIxIIcKlpBQ4NkBRxlMJEmJJloxXAUDVRkhbPY4Kr1RMmEhAorlZ5dt40sb9rr9eRxYbhqDEslUspbWCHZNLdaatTaUhidKaXS3S4KJ0KBRMIUOBgChw4B5PBsAEIMfTAVQACieDwwy0q6ICbiVNWUUmOnycAGskAx5i5lLSGJ0siB3mgggBpKufFEsS5ISId6vsgCU81cq3Dke+YljXkTydTMAAPAARVi9-tVuCNbgcSIsdkAPgzqLVzXZbTzWUNxdL7J0Fc77NrSo4DabLfbj7z5zXhIHylXHs-yrVwR0OJw2zgTg4EA9cB2fPMujHMMIyjac4znFN00zU8c3ZK8i2kW9vzgB9BzzZ960bAtmxgVt-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-3KexFTmPx-jpfs9zntLAeAuS9UJxuZcToreH2kB9eoWqBFu2Dq5RpIFgEq+GqLBUKnGMZWntMZFXhwHQNoxisGATUM0LBwGeGdPaFIUDzJejpPuC2-J5ZCggKkPK3F-rwCeAkVsdAeBJ28k4fA+hCiVnwDofAwxywMCMMqSsUB8BuF9ocWEcRQElG4QAVQQPoBBcYfDKGEfwwRcQ7TgkdOkF0KRxEIJCAocIsxohwCUWECIkRxFdDgIodhMhYSfGHmqcYuN3B7BJP4LI8Q4EyMvAWDRKioj-DMoAhU9tdLCKsc4CaM54w8CTNDNMYiBEIMNJAmhxxqEEG+L8JA+AhweNWiY7UuMzIYUCfObCfCwnQK1OMKJswYn4FhIk5Jw1bHSLSIYzGjEkQokRv4JCfjMlQCCQuDMUiHQKPyd0+BRTPAxLIWUmhDTUSsKSewpxWj0neTaR09MMzVHiOgUgn0CD8DRLGciCZj9xQPHgMkDQQRsYnO4JEUOZlYQrRiseAhQQiFQB8K7dmQRsF6VwYVQGDRhioCgK2a5YREBIA0JTBoil8EAsecQlgZdFIbHstpaWaZVaIv2tLOS9UICcDTPgco5SCAaGAIkra6jgAnLOUEC5VzvLHNORS6lfZQ6HQqkgMANIhixRqGmIgPy-kPJoYuZsUBywHmVnzK2IqxWJNZUQDl-BuWeDTFQNMi4AA6VBpWd2FQkMVVArD4GVl7XVoqx4sA0gAIhYIUWqTwACOhQgYwEtQeWVni2UKq5Ty1VGqtV6oPOqlgQ5TX6sNca0N5qrU2rtUgR1zrrD8FdaSxU3d-oQAeKzCAGh-5VIdCwfaK0zoCSFiLc1ocrWANdfrMtG845h0tYApWsJLVMVpIDHAxRPAMD+TAAAkhwYGAAJOgABZfQUspC52pSAE49KqU0ozp0OAVBr66SkIDYG7wDDg0hsE2h3CSmpPGDE49rAu6HQ3UDHg26wYIz7PuodoRnGRBKcsqIMT33hW7npK9W7Qa7oeFDTp+BYpgGYGCKCHASneJid4i9ni-03oA-e4D6Z8CCC8BAC5R7+mpFPXhtgnjxTwqUrUhQOhxmeF0cWVkcISJUf+P1bSsJPKTV2dR+6eg9FwGlpa1WsJOittVlR7WuVnq33voqb65BOhAA) to the complete code, and here is the `filterByList` signature.

```
function filterByList(select: string | string[], all: {url: string, [key: string]: any}[], matchKey: string, desiredKey: string): string[];
function filterByList<DesiredKey extends string>(select: string | string[], all: {url: string, [key: string]: any}[], matchKey: string, desiredKey: DesiredKey[]): { [K in DesiredKey]: string }[];
function filterByList(select: string | string[], all: {url: string, [key: string]: any}[], matchKey: string, desiredKey: string | string[]) {
...
}
```

You can learn more about *generics* [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I definitely need to brush up on generics. I stared at this problem for way too long. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've stripped a lot out of this to try to make the more general part of the answer clearer. If the list of desired fields/keys truly is dynamic, then you won't be able to do this. If your implementation specifies which keys will be fetched, then you're in luck.

The key is using the `ArrayOfKeysType[number]` construct. In concrete terms, if the array of keys is `['name', 'model']`, then the "number" is either 0 or 1 (the array indices), and the resulting type will have the values "name" and "model". Those can in turn be used as the keys for a `Record`.

[In the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgdgJQsArgJzgSzgcwMqQDGmMmEAJgGJkA25AzgDwCwAUFFAPIBGAVhIWAAVcBAA0bDtQh16UCAA9gEOAygAKesDTYcUAD5Q4KALbcIaA1HogzAexoBKANoBdKAF4NAawgg7MFx8AsKiLq4SrAB8nhqSUHbBgvQAXEH8giKQblYoqhCkcBSRHKQyDGnSspGOnjHO8UiEdmjkjFUMzsZmFhHW2rpRka4A3Gxs2MpoMACGhNB4wDNo9AAWmGBZ0ADe8c1aAPrYB4RoFJjAqf06uPEmduQyaVo3OGPsRjMmEM8DuO8cdA0X6vd4AX3ebGacC01nWYCui2Waw2WxyXgaH12Hw4%202ARzgJzO5AuVwA5ABGAAMVLJJQ4UHuj2BUDJlDp8Q4cC%20P1ZlDsdg5OKgQLSZNWwGACJSAHoZVplgA6FFgGUwAVk%20Jg%20nYhlQPEEonnS5i6m0%20kcJlPVkAISFeu53zFNuW9oZotZEqlqTlCrQyvhMu4rq1kTYo3GrGhsJwyB4GWAAAVlsBMDMaLF1IkE-QxLBaAxah4YrqoGdUBgEklLoqTDMwOos3wiyXOWXkOg4PnyvRFcSUPNG2AU2maHmynQW1BS3rh2hU%20nnBPyO4vNmlwWI8KOOXO1A5wuaACGdrp2DHCMoFqL2wIZHo8A4RsAHI8uRedSx4DxkLJ%20ejqAZjkeAkArLBcAIAQSDIKgCyYJEVnhLY82cMkrRoOlWUdCAyVcKJHE0eFcygVD0MwslsNwm9WChOwYUfdU7FiFVX2%20ehnCpLdGNrB4ZHebjsP4gVFSBS85SgbAADd00wcgoHMQgZhQehoDomgQEZXiMxmVRPm%20eQFEwLQgA)

`getObjectPartial()` is untyped for simplicity, so you'll have to ignore the any-errors. Aside from that, you'll see that the only error is when trying to access the url property, which isn't in the set of requested keys. You'll notice that `['model', 'name']` is repeated twice toward the end, but that's to use it once as a type and again as a value/parameter. This, and many other parts of this example should be cleaned up in a production implementation.

```
type fnReturningSpecifiedFields<
  ObjectType,
  Fields extends (string | number | symbol)[] = (keyof ObjectType)[],
> = (
  objects: ObjectType[] | undefined,
  fields: Fields,
) => [
  Record<Fields[number], string>,
];

interface StarshipType {
  cost_in_credits: string
  model: string;
  name: string;
  url: string;
};

const ships: StarshipType[] = [
  {
    cost_in_credits: '100',
    model: 'F',
    name: 'Foo',
    url: 'https://star.ship/foo'
  },
  {
    cost_in_credits: '100',
    model: 'B',
    name: 'Bar',
    url: 'https://star.ship/bar'
  },

];

const getObjectPartial = (objects, fields) => {
  return objects.map((obj) => {
    return fields.reduce((partial, field) => {
      partial[field] = obj[field];
      return partial;
    }, {}); 
  });
};

const shipNames = (getObjectPartial as fnReturningSpecifiedFields<StarshipType, ['model', 'name']>)(ships, ['model', 'name']);

const foo = shipNames[0];
foo.model;
foo.name;
foo.url; // invalid because only model and name exist
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, and for slimming down the example to be more concise. I'm looking over your solution, but I don't see where your proposed solution discerns between the two different argument types `string` vs. `string[]`. Where is that logic?

Comment: It doesn't. The easiest thing for you to do is to use string[] all the time, with it sometimes having a single element. I was outlining the most difficult part of what you're asking for, which is the extraction of array elements as keys.